# Scapy problems when importing modules

Tags: python, scapy

I recently started programming in python and scapy. But when i use from scapy.all import * it doesnt work and i get the exception ImportError: No module named 'base_classes'. So it is finding the folder all, but cannot find base_classes. I verified however that base_classes is actually in there. In extend, import scapy.all.base_classes finds that there are base_classes in there but when i execute it i stil get an error. What should i do? i verified my version of scapy and it is 2.x.

Thank you
Martinos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into a similar issue once and it was because I wasn't using the right version of python and the right python path.

I solved it by adding the right classes to the path in the beginning of my script using

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/home/me/mypy")
```

It's a bit ugly but it worked.

Comment: how can i determine which is the "right" version of python to use? Also, does it matter that i use windows?

Comment: I think scary is made for 2.5. I don't know about windows though sorry!