# Scapy In A Script

Tags: python, scapy

I have used scapy as a session in python, but I want to use it in a script. Why so? I want to be able to use `sys.argv` to specify an IP address to use as well as use other modules. How can this be accomplished?

Comment: if I get your question correctly, you dont want to use scapy Interface, but rather import scapy in other scripts right? you can do it by importing all.. 'from scapy.all import * ' should get you going

Comment: that gives me an error that there is no `base_modules` module

Comment: can you put the complete error?

Comment: looks like someone else too faced the error - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17704520/scapy-problems-when-importing-modules?rq=1

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You just need to import it, as any other Python module.

```
from scapy.layers.inet import IP, ICMP
from scapy.sendrecv import sr
import sys
sr(IP(dst=sys.argv[1])/ICMP())
```

Or if you want to import everything at once:

```
import scapy.all as scapy
import sys
scapy.sr(scapy.IP(dst=sys.argv[1])/scapy.ICMP())
[...]
```

Or if you want to code exactly as in the Scapy console:

```
from scapy.all import *
import sys
sr(IP(dst=sys.argv[1])/ICMP())
```

Comment: Hi @Pierre, I got this error when I tried to run the Scapy code embedded in a python script file.ubuntu@sdnhubvm:~[16:12]$ python scapy.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scapy.py", line 8, in <module>
    from scapy.all import *
  File "/home/ubuntu/scapy.py", line 8, in <module>
    from scapy.all import *
ImportError: No module named all

Is this due to location of my python script?
How to solve it. I want to just use scapy ping inside that script and Test if it is sending packet to the destination specified in dst.

Comment: You should probably not name your script `scapy.py`.

Comment: when you do `scapy.sr(scapy.IP(dst=sys.argv[1])/scapy.ICMP())` what does the `\` mean/do??

Comment: Sorry @DavidDias but I don't understand your question. May be you have forgotten something between the `` chars?

Comment: I'm sorry Pierre, you are right, there is a char missing, what does the `/` do then you have that expression?

Comment: `/` is the encapsulation operator. That means ICMP encapsulated in IP.